# Concentration of salts

Tags: diffusion

I would like to know the answer about this question. As you know, the concentration of salts in the ocean tends to increase with the depth. In the Marianas Trench there is more salt dissolved per liter than in the middle height of the ocean. The more down you go, more salt per liter of water (probably due to pressure). My question is the following: if I could bring the salts from the surface down to the bed of the ocean, would the water increase her salinity or through dilution, diffusion, the ocean would repristinate the same gradient of salinity?

Answer (score -1):

I read that because of gravitation, in a long long (long?) time, the ions will precipitate down at the bottom. Something reproducible faster in the centrifuge, like that separates proteins or DNA from liquids.